# Why is $\{\omega \in \Omega: \sup_n f_n>c\}=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\{\omega \in \Omega: f_n>c\}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_1,f_2,...$ are borel measurable, real-valued functions.

Why is $\{\omega \in \Omega: \sup_n f_n>c\}=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\{\omega \in \Omega: f_n>c\}$?

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: Also, would this statement be true if I were to substitute > by ≥?

Comment: Because, if $(x_n)\subset\mathbb R$, then $$\sup x_n>x\iff\exists n\ x_n>x$$ Hence the inequality is pure real analysis, noting about probability in it.

Comment: Furthermore, $$\exists n\ x_n\geqslant x\implies\sup x_n\geqslant x\implies\forall\epsilon>0\ \exists n\ x_n\geqslant x-\epsilon$$ but the equivalence does not hold.

Comment: @Did thanks for the comments. Is the 2nd implication in your second comment also an equivalence? Also, is that definition or epsilon property usual to use? I didn't find it in wikipedia... Thanks

Comment: "Is the 2nd implication in your second comment also an equivalence?" You know what, maybe writing down the definition of the supremum in front of you on a piece of paper and *thinking* hard about it would help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** check the double inclusion: $\supseteq$ is easy, $\subseteq$ needs to exploit the $\sup$ definition.

EDIT

Let's pick $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $\sup_nf_n(\omega)>c$; now notice that $\{f_n(\omega)\}_n$ is a real sequence, thus by definition of supremum, either there exists $\bar n$ s.t. $f_{\bar n}(\omega)>c$ (and we would have finished), or $\forall\varepsilon>0\;\;\exists n_{\varepsilon}$ s.t. the $n_{\varepsilon}$-tail of our sequence is contained in the $\varepsilon$-right-nhbd of $c$, from which we conclude.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For the second part, can you give a hint? I've tried to find a definition of sup which also included unions, sth similar to lim sup, but couldn't find it... Also, would this statement be true if I were to substitute $>$ by $\geq$?

Comment: Joe, thanks for your answer. Could you translate into mathematical expression your last sentence, please? Also, is that epsilon property of usual use? I didn't find it in wikipedia...

Comment: Try to convert my sentences into formulas by your own, that's the way you *really* learn Math